# Is there a dataset for OCR of handwritten texts available?

Tags: data-request, unstructured-data

I would like to evaluate an idea for OCR of handwritten texts (especially with mathematical contents).

Is there a dataset for OCR of handwritten texts available? It should contain images of documents, e.g. something like

[image]

It would be good (but not necessary) if the dataset contained information about the language(s) of the document and probably also the topic.

### Side questions

I'm not sure how OCR algorithms are evaluated, as OCR contains multiple problems:

1. Segmentation: Find single entities in the source image
2. Classification: Classify the segmented images
3. Placement: Find the relationship between two classified symbols (is one to the right of the other or rather the the right-top? Hence: Is it `ax` or `a^x`?

I'm also not sure how such a dataset should be labeled. But for this question, I would also accept datasets which do not contain labels.

Comment: Probably [icdar2011competition](http://www.cvc.uab.es/icdar2011competition/). I've just registered, but I'm waiting for an email right now.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://www.iapr-tc11.org/mediawiki/index.php/CROHME:_Competition_on_Recognition_of_Online_Handwritten_Mathematical_Expressions) ?

Comment: @ettore this is an online recognition dataset. Ocr is offline recognition

Comment: Yes, but i've seen [here](https://github.com/falvaro/seshat) that the inkml dataset can be converted to png. I thought that it could be usefull for you (Another well known [database of handwriting texts](http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/databases/iam-handwriting-database), by the way).